# How do I create and call a custom named function?

Tags: theming, 9

Brand new to Drupal and I need to figure out how to create a custom function and call the custom function in the twig file.

I need to build a news releases function that reads a directory and pulls the PDF files for a corresponding year. (This should be easy enough in PHP.)

The missing key is where and how to create a custom function and how to call this custom function in the template file.

A few hours of searching lead me to create this.

#### <MY_CUSTOM_THEME_NAME>.theme

```php
function <MY_CUSTOM_THEME_NAME>_preprocess(&$variables, $hook) {
  $x = "hello world";
  $variables['helloworld'] = $x;
}
```

#### news-releases.html.twig

```
<section>
  <h1>{{ helloworld }}</h1>
  <p>Lorem ipsum...</p>
</section>
```

#### Result

```html
<h1>hello world</h1>
```

Sifting through all the searches and YouTube videos, nobody has explained or shown documentation for Drupal 9 on how to create a custom named function. Is this even possible?

This is the desired result.

#### Any file

```php
function hello_world($year) {
  $directory = "/news/releases/" . $year;
  $scan_directory = array_diff(scandir($directory), array('..', '.'));
}
```

#### Any template file

```
<section>
  {% for newsrelease in newsreleases %}
    <li class="news-release-item">{{ newsrelease }}</li>
  {% endfor %}
</section>
```

I am not sure on how I can pass a variable back into the custom function so the correct directory will be scanned. Not sure if I would have to just create 5 separate functions for each year and call the correct year like the twig snippet.

I've been googling "Drupal 9 custom modules" and dug up nothing to further my quest. If the answer does happen to be "create a custom module" then how do I include the custom module as apart of my existing custom theme?

I am using Drupal 9.1.x and I have read https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/core%21core.api.php/group/hooks/9.1.x already.

Comment: What you are describing here is a Twig function, you'll find a lot of blog posts when google for `drupal custom twig function`. **BUT:** This is not how Drupal commonly works. Templates only render stuff they are given, they shall not fetch data themselves. So yes, the answer is *create a custom module*.

Comment: I agree with Hudri. Templates are part of the theming layer - they are for wrapping generated data in HTML (or XML or JSON or whatever). The actual data generation comes at the module layer. As you are trying to generate data, it should not be done at the twig layer, as it will miss a number of Drupal APIs.